# On Click.. Add Div text to another DIV with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add city name inside `filter_selected_det` container.

Working: whatever `<a>` element clicked, it removes previous city name and replace with clicked city name.

Solution Needed:

Example. 'Perth' city name clicked.. it have to add to 'filter_selected_det'. Another city name 'Sydney' clicked, it have to add with existing 'Perth' like 'Perth, Sydney'. Like wise 'Perth, Sydney, Krabi, Melbourne'

if it exceeds maximum 3 cities selected.. it should not add.

please let me know comments.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="filter_selected_det">

</div>
<div class="city_container">
    <a href="#">Perth</a>
    <a href="#">Sydney</a>
    <a href="#">Krabi</a>
    <a href="#">Melbourne</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.city_container a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var $selectCities = $(this).html();
    $('.filter_selected_det').html($selectCities);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append new city, not replace all html:

```
$('.city_container a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var newCity = $('<div/>').html($(this).html());
    $('.filter_selected_det').append(newCity);
});
```

and you can add comma in css like:

```
.filter_selected_det > div { display: inline }
.filter_selected_det > div:not(:first-child):before { content: ','; display: inline }
```

Comment: Hi Artem.. thanks. it works. Small updates.. By default, ''filter_selected_det' div will have "All cities" text. Have to remove this once any city selected. That's it. Now, selected cities are adding with "All cities".

Comment: wrap all cities in a div with any classname and .remove() it by this classname

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the current DIV content with the new content:

```
$('.filter_selected_det').html($('.filter_selected_det').html() + ',' + $selectCities);
```

Comment: It will not work, $selectCities redefined inside function